# Photoshop: How to export all objects from a jpg image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export

I have an image with several elements. I would like to export them all.

The only way I found is to let the Object Selection tool automatically find all objects in my image, then one by one make a layer and export that layer to PNG. The problem is, every time I create a new layer, I have to select the original layer again, triggering the object detection all over again, which takes about 15 seconds each time. Is there a way to keep in memory the object detection? Or another way to achieve my goal?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would not use PS for this, but a vector-based program. Illustrator, Corel, Inkscape perhaps.

1. Draw individual circles or ellipses on the shapes.

[image]

3. Use Power Clip or Clipping Mask and put the image inside the shape.
4. The file could result in a big file because you have several copies of your raster image.
5. Export your circles.

---

But if you have access to the collection... Take the photo again. Separate them and be careful not to take the photo from an angle, but exactly (as you can) from the top.

And use a flat background. Put on a white sheet of paper.

And if it is to show them individually, it is WAY easier to take individual shots.